# XP reboots when I use uTorrent

Tags: windows-xp, reboot, minidumps, dump

Maybe it's a hard-disk fault, but I don't think so. Ran some tests and all says the HDD is in green condition, all test passed. Memory is a Geil ULTRA, guess that's not a problem either.

Basically if I run uTorrent about ~80mbps speed (thats my home connection atm), it'll restart the PC. I don't know how, or why. In the log it says "The PC has been rebooted to check for errors. .... The memory dump have been saved into the following file."

The error message in hungarian (since its a hungarian XP):
`Az operációs rendszer hibakeresés céljából újraindította a számítógépet. A művelet a következő volt: 0x100000d1 (0x0000002c, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, 0xa94a9a8c). A memóriakép mentve a következő fájlba: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\Mini092210-07.dmp.`

The mainboard is an Intel GCLF945. HDD is a Seagate 320gb Sata2. 
Nothing extraordinary.
XP SP3 + Avast! Home.

I can provide the mini-dumps if you need em.
uTorrent version: 2.0.4

Comment: Was the torrent resumed in Ubuntu and and then back in Windows ?

Comment: No no.. I only use XP on the PC at the moment. Back then there was an Ubuntu installation and Arch linux before that ..but... Linux couldn't really perform good enough. (The VNC/NX problems.. oh..well won't list them. :))

Comment: Ah. The reason I asked was uTorrent/Vista would consistently BSOD on me on occasion - the occasion being me having resumed the torrent in Ubuntu. Curiously, only torrents being resumed in Ubuntu were having this, not in openSUSE. ( yeah, I had triple boot, and I'm rambling. I'll shut up now). @Shiki

Comment: Ah no problem. I was always rambling too as you may have noticed back then when I had more time / was more active on SU. Now with only Microsoft Win7/XP I rant about 700% less which is just awesome. Anyway, I still keep getting ipv6 BSODs so ... Win7, come forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BlueScreenView](http://nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to try and analyze the dumps and add to your post the highlighted results displayed in the lower pane :

> BlueScreenView scans all your minidump
>   files created during 'blue screen of
>   death' crashes, and displays the
>   information about all crashes in one
>   table. For each crash, BlueScreenView
>   displays the minidump filename, the
>   date/time of the crash, the basic
>   crash information displayed in the
>   blue screen (Bug Check Code and 4
>   parameters), **and the details of the driver or module that possibly caused the crash** (filename, product name,
>   file description, and file
>   version). 
> **For each crash displayed in the upper pane, you can view the details of the device drivers
>   loaded during the crash in the lower
>   pane**. **BlueScreenView also marks the
>   drivers that their addresses found in
>   the crash stack, so you can easily
>   locate the suspected drivers that
>   possibly caused the crash**.

Comment: AWESOME. The IPV6.sys caused the problems. Darn you IPv6. :)

Comment: Also: Had to disable ipv6 in uTorrent/advanced AND update realtek drivers. Sheesh.

Comment: Update: still not working, reboot occurs. Maybe I'll just install a Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: You can also disable ipv6 in properties of network adapter -> tcp/ip properties.

Answer (score 2):

Excert from another answer I wrote:

It is impossible for programs that simply run as software to cause system instability or crashes.

What commonly happens, especially with torrent programs is that they simply tax the system to the maximum and can make weaknesses in other areas show up.

I had this in Utorrent a while ago, it turned out to be a bad [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw) network driver. I went to their [site](http://www.realtek.com.tw) and updated to the latest driver which did fix the problem - I am not sure if you are also using a Realtek card, but if you are, I certainly would upgrade.

...80Mb at home? Lucky!

To test if you are affected, try opening a network drive (if you have any) and transfer a file over 1GB for a prolonged period of time - for me, **ANY** file transfer that put the NIC at above ~70% usage for more than a minute caused a blue screen error.

As Harrymc said, Nirsoft Bluescreenview is also a good utility for seeing past problems (if you have automatic restart on system failures set). However, it does not always come up with the network driver as the fault, so it can take some digging.

Comment: Hmm no matter how I stress it, it won't reboot. Pushing Steam content files through lan at full throttle, but no effect at all. :/